# A huge desert full of green sand, seated on a plateau, is steadily drained into the nearby lowlands. What happens to the environment?

Tags: science-based, climate, fauna, flora

I have a large plateau, and roughly in the center are mile-high cliffs surrounding a valley.

Inside the valley is a green sandy desert. The sand is composed of olivine. Unfortunately for the inhabitants of the green desert, a hostile power has resolved to remove all the sand out of the valley, off of the plateau, and into the lowlands below it via a huge ramp/shaft that they dug and some vague (and very classified) magic trickery.

What does this do to the local climate? Is a desert in a closed-off valley even entirely possible?

Of equal interest: what happens to the lowlands? This particular area of them where the sand is being drained is a region of badlands. Keep in mind that it isn't all of the sand being dumped at once, but rather a steady (albeit massive) flow of the stuff.

And what would happen to the flora and fauna on both ends?

Comment: Do you want the sand to flow like water? Does it have any special qualities apart from its color?

Comment: @Alexander Nope. Just sand. Lots and lots of sand. I'm not too concerned with the physics of how it gets from the desert to the point of falling into the badlands, unless that severely alters answers to the rest of the question.

Comment: What's the sand made of?

Comment: "*a hostile power has resolved to remove all the sand out of the valley*"  **Why**, for Heaven's sake?

Comment: FYI: [Angle of repose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose). For dry sand, its 34 degrees. Sand will not flow down if its slope is less than 34 degrees.

Comment: "*What does this do to the local climate?*"  Why should it do anything to the climate?

Comment: "*Is a desert in a closed-off valley even entirely possible?*"  Sure.  "Desert" just means "no rain", and that can happen for a lot of reasons.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_shadow for one reason.

Comment: "*And what would happen to the flora and fauna on both ends?*" It's a desert up top an badlands below.  There's not that much to worry about...

Comment: @RonJohn It is made of [olivine.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivine) The hostile power's motivations are hardly relevant to the question, but suffice it to say that it's a brute-force and roundabout way of committing genocide for a variety of reasons. As for your last question, I'm not a climate scientist, even by armchair qualifications. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: "*a brute-force and roundabout way of committing genocide*"  Since nothing grows in tiny crystals of olivine (or silica for that matter), it's not a very good method of committing genocide.  Exposing the rock below might even improve their lives, since there wouldn't be anymore olivine sand anymore.

Comment: @RonJohn Again, not relevant to the question, but these aren't humans they're committing genocide against. They're a species entirely dependent upon the existence of their desert without much ability to live in other climates.

Comment: "*these aren't humans ... entirely dependent upon the existence of their desert*" without telling us this, we naturally presume that the inhabitants are human, and thus consider how it would affect humans.  But since they **aren't** humans, any answer given would be Primarily Opinion Based, and that's a Vote To Close reason.

Comment: @RonJohn Except I'm not asking about the inhabitants, I'm asking about the natural world around them. I couldn't care less what happens to the inhabitants for the purposes of this question; I'll do some handwavium in my story regarding that.

Comment: "*I'm asking about the natural world around them.*"  Well, what **does* happen when you pour a bunch of sand on something?

Comment: @ronjohn This is purely a question about ecological effects. None of that other stuff matters. It's not nearly that complicated, and the presence of predictable environmental effects makes this not opinion based.

Comment: @classifiedangel I'm trying to understand this setup: so, at the bottom are badlands, that the sand is draining into, and in the center of the badlands are a large plateau, and in the center of the plateau is a valley containing the desert? Apologies if I'm being dense, could you walk us through the geography?

Comment: (a) Olivine sand is not dirt.  There is little flora, and therefore little or no fauna.  (b) If you remove all the topsoil (necessitating plowing up all the flora), flora has trouble living and therfore fauna dies.  (c) You have not described the ecosystem of your valley, and without it this question is impossible to answer.  Above all, where's the water coming from?  Rain?  Aquifer?  (d) Yes, deserts in closed off valleys are possible.